# cleos: add auth level to account with specific key pair and limited permissions

Tags: accounts, action, permissions, keys

Each EOS account has two key pairs: "@owner" and "@active". I want to add another key pair under the name "@limited" which I can use in an unsafe environment (VPS) to interact only with specific actions of specific smart contracts. Since I don't trust the VPS provider this new key pair "myaccount@limited" should only be able to execute specific actions of certain smart contracts. **I want this new key "@limited" to not have any permissions at all except for those actions I explicitly add to it.**

So far I have this:

1. generate a new key pair for EOS accounts with: `cleos create key`
2. try to bind this new public key to myaccount under "@limited" with: `cleos set account permission myaccount limited EOS6dXnCnYMENbgY4i7Vx7fsqTbRGPiSNXoZ3tB5xS2M3n7SNaskK owner -p myaccount@owner`
3. add permission for actions to @limited

but 2) fails with the following error message: `3489819ms thread-0   main.cpp:2712                 main                 ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10) response_content_length >= 0: Invalid content-length response`

I read through all the documentation I could find but couldn't really figure it out yet. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Here is a good article about exactly that from EOS New York: https://medium.com/eos-new-york/creating-a-custom-eos-permission-8626d77fb7df

Bloks.io has a great UI for custom permissions which can be found here: https://bloks.io/wallet/permissions